# Nginx Redirect issue

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect, ssl-certificate, nginx-config

i installed nginx on ubunto 18.4 and create html page with 'hallo world' message in the /var/www/html path.

I create self-signed SSL certificate,
using this guide [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%93-enabling-the-changes-in-nginx)

and I want to Redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS.

this is the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file configuration:

```
server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            listen [::]:443 ssl;
            include snippets/self-signed.conf;
            include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
            
            root /var/www/html;
    
            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
            server_name _;
    
            location / {
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
    
             
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://35.180.25.62$request_uri; 
}
```

**THE PROBLAME:**

in the browser,when i enter https://35.180.25.62 - i get the 'hallow world' page. (good)

but, when i enter http://35.180.25.62 - i dont get the 'hallow world' page. (bad)

i want that when i enter http://35.180.25.62 - nginx will use the ssl and show me the 'hallow world' page.

**i also notis-**

1.when i enter http://35.180.25.62 in the browser, i check in the browser developer tools (f12),
and the redirection take me to 5.180.25.62 insted 35.180.25.62!!! whay?
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDuwh.png)

2.only when i enter http://35.180.25.62/index.html - the redirection is good and i get the 'hallow world' page.
whay when i enter https://35.180.25.62 i didnt have to write the 'index.html' , but in the http i have?